# How to retrieve Latitude and Longitude quickly in android?

Tags: android

I am using LocationManager to get the values of Latitude and Longitude of a user.

In some of the devices onLocationChanged is called quickly and in some devices a bit late. Is this problem depends on device or anything else. Please help me.

Comment: depends on network state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency that this is called depends on nothing other then the LocationManager and the device itself.